# Infinite Mandelbrot set zoom becomes pixelated

Tags: glsl, shader

I am working on a Mandelbrot shader for my computer science class and I am having a problem when you zoom in a lot.

It becomes very pixelated as you can see in the screenshot (but only when you zoom in enough).

It is coded in Python with Pygame and ModernGL, and uses glsl for the shaders (idk if anyone would need to know that or if there's more kinds of shader languages?)

The repo that I uploaded it to can be found at [GitGub Link](https://github.com/RottenAppleSalt/ApProject/tree/main)

In the shader itself I have values that I calculate for what to show (zoom and camera position) that I know can be used to find what part of the fractal is on screen, but I have no clue how to make it render the selected area in higher detail.
`mandelbrot.frag`

```
// Change coordinates
float a = -1.95 * zoom;
float b = 1.95 * zoom;
float c = -1.1 * zoom;
float d = 1.1 * zoom;
```

I am very VERY new to shaders and have only made one project with them before (with very heavy guidance from youtube).

What I tried was making it so that you can increase the iterations with zoom or manual increasing iterations (the current version) but either way it still is just pixelated.

Could it be in here?
`mandelbrot.frag`

```
// Curent pixel in mandelbrot?
    bool is_bounded = true;
    float age = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if(z.x*z.x + z.y*z.y > THRESHOLD) {
            is_bounded = false;
            break;
        }
        
        // Calculate Zn+1
        vec2 z_new;
        
        z_new.x = z.x*z.x - z.y*z.y;
        z_new.y = 2.*z.x*z.y;
        
        z_new += uv;
        
        // Update z
        z = z_new;
        age++;
    }
```

Ask me any questions, thanks!

Comment: Floating point types -- `float`, `double` etc. -- have a finite precision.  So if you zoom in sufficiently far you'll find that adjacent screen pixels actually map to the same Mandelbrot coordinates.  Hence the apparent pixelation.

Answer (score 1):

the reason you're getting pixelation is that you're running into the edge of float precision for differentiating between regions.

**normal case:** Each pixel is far enough apart that they all have different values for their center location.

**super zoomed-in case:** The zoom level is so high that floats are not precise enough to have different values for adjacent pixels.

This will always happen with all infinite zoom shader projects. You could zoom in further if you were able to use double precision, and you could go to heroic lengths to calculate more precision, but it will always happen at some level of zoom.